# Regex to match URL not followed by " or <

Tags: regex, url, pattern-matching

I'm trying to modify the url-matching regex at http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls to not match anything that's already part of a valid URL tag or used as the link text.

For example, in the following string, I want to match http://www.foo.com, but NOT http://www.bar.com or http://www.baz.com

```
www.foo.com <a href="http://www.bar.com">http://www.baz.com</a>
```

I was trying to add a negative lookahead to exclude matches followed by " or <, but for some reason, it's only applying to the "m" in .com.  So, this regex still returns http://www.bar.co and http://www.baz.co as matches.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong... any ideas?

```
\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))(?!["<])
```

Here is a simpler example too:

```
((((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)|(www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.:#/~}?]+)(?!["<])
```

Comment: I always think using a Regular Expression Testing tool helps!  
http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Thanks.  I've been using one of those. I'll try this one too to see if it offers any other hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, its actually trivial to make it work if you just want to exclude trailing characters, just make your expression 'independent', then no backtracking will occurr in that segment.

`(?>\b ...)(?!["<])`

A perl test:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'www.foo.com <a href="http://www.bar.com">http://www.baz.com</a>http://www.some.com';

while ($str =~ m~
 (?>
    \b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
 )
 (?!["<])
~xg)
{
   print "$1\n";
}
```

Output:

`www.foo.com`
`http://www.some.com`

Answer (score 2):

I looked into this issue last year and developed a solution that you may want to look at - See: [URL Linkification (HTTP/FTP)](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/linkifyurl/linkify.html) This link is a test page for the Javascript solution with many examples of difficult-to-linkify URLs.

My regex solution, written for both PHP and Javascript - is not simple (but neither is the problem as it turns out.) For more information I would recommend also reading:

[The Problem With URLs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html) by Jeff Atwood, and
[An Improved Liberal, Accurate Regex Pattern for Matching URLs](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) by John Gruber

The comments following Jeff's blog post are a must read if you want to do this right...

Note also that John Gruber's regex has a component that can go into realm of catastrophic backtracking (the part which matches one level of matching parentheses).

Comment: Thanks. This is a very helpful list of url formats.  I think the crux of my question is more about how to exclude URLs from being matched when they're followed by a " or < character.  I thought grouping the match and following with a negative-lookahead would work, but it appears to only exclude the last letter of the match (e.g. the m in .com).